# Like permalink on typepad?

Tags: facebook-like, blogs

I'm having an issue with http://blogs.salesforce.com. The like buttons should like the targeted blog however it does not actually share the page on facebook or do anything for that matter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric,
Running one of the blog posts through the [Debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2012/08/how-best-in-class-teams-win.html) shows an issue with the og:url tag. It can't be empty, and should point to a valid url (current url), same for description. Without that, the Likes on the blog will work but they won't be Share-able on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with the open graph tags. The previous developer left them all empty.